# Получить данные из Notification для обновления

Tags: android, android-notification

Есть отправленый `Notification`, пользователь его не смахнул, необходимо вытащить из него данные (конкретно `Number`) для обновления - к примеру: в первом уведомлении было скачано 5 новостей, уведомление висит в статус-баре, новое уведомление с 7 новостями должно вывести сумму предыдущего и своего - т.е. 12.
На данный момент написал простенький метод, но работает только начиная с API 23. Может кто сталкивался и делал подобное для более ранних версий? Текущий код:

```
public static int getNumberInIssetNotification(int id, NotificationManager notificationManager){
    int number = 0;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        StatusBarNotification[] statusBarNotifications = notificationManager.getActiveNotifications();

        for(StatusBarNotification statusBarNotification : statusBarNotifications)
            if(statusBarNotification.getId() == id){
                Notification notification = statusBarNotification.getNotification();
                number = notification.number;
            }
    }

    return number;
}
```

Все бы хорошо, но метод `getActiveNotifications()` конкретно с API 23...

**UPD**
Можно повесть сервис по примеру: [NotificationListenerService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926236/notificationlistenerservice-implementation) - минимальный API 18, но плюс сервис...

Comment: А если сохранять предыдущее значение, например в префы и брать от туда и плюсовать? А при кэнселе - обнулять.

Comment: @eugeneek а как ловить момент когда пользователь смахивает `notification`?

Comment: С помошью [DeleteIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#DeleteIntent). Вот пример на [англ. SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20670984/3069565)

Comment: @eugeneek интересно, я пока только сервисом нашел - обновил в вопросе, вечером попробую вашу ссылку.

Comment: @eugeneek поставьте ваше предложение по нанглийской ссылке SO как ответ - помечу правильным, все отлично работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как альтернативный вариант, сохранять предыдущее значение `Number`, например в префы и брать от туда и плюсовать. А при кэнселе нотификейшна - обнулять сохранённое значение.

Отследить кансел можно с помощью [DeleteIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#DeleteIntent). Пример реализации [есть тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671453/catch-on-swipe-to-dismiss-event/20670984#20670984).

Comment: оставил первоначальный вариант для API 23+, ваш вариант работает на API 18+